# How to refer to application_item in css

Tags: css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

This is my first time here, so be gentle :)
I am using APEX 5.1 and try to use a simple css code to change the color of the header-branding. So far so good, but I like to get the color out of the application item `P_OMGEVING_COLOR`, which contains dynamic colors (The application_item is getting the right value).

I found a lot of help on the internet, but unfortunately I still cannot get it to work.

The below css style is the problem:

---

```css
.t-Header-branding 
{
    background-color: apex.item( "P_OMGEVING_COLOR" ).getValue();
}
```

---

I tried the folowing:

1. `&P_OMGEVING_COLOR`
2. `#P_OMGEVING_COLOR#`
3. `$x("P_OMGEVING_COLOR").value;`

Comment: What's Apex 5.1? Please link to resource.

Comment: apex.oracle.com. Apex is rad software thats connected to an oracle database. here you can set up values in page items or application items, which i want to use in css code

Comment: I don't understand. Your item contains value which you want to use as color for CSS class? Or what?

Comment: yes thats basically it. i want the application change color for every OTAP environment.

Comment: problem is solved. thread can be closed

Comment: You can write the answer below and mark it as solved, it will help other people who will encounter the same problem.

Comment: i tried to use dynamic css in the themeroller in apex, but i had to use it in page 0. there i refer to $P_OMGEVING_COLOR.